# How to make LocalDate.now() as a table name in Java

Tags: java, sqlite

I have been working on a project in which i need to make Table names as per current date so that new table according to date everyday. 
I tried to apply it in Sqlite like but it won't work.

always gives the following error
[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "20180215": syntax error)

```
 String s="create table if not exists "+LocalDate.now().toString().replaceAll("-","")+" ( id integer primany " +
                "key autoincrement not null, sender text not null, receiever text not null, fathername" +
                " text not null, money integer not null);";
```

`LocalDate.now().toString().replaceAll("-","")`

`[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "20180215": syntax error)`

Comment: This sounds like a really horrible design for a relational database. You should reconsider you approach.

Comment: how would you name a table tomorrow? how many tables will you own?

Comment: Wow change your DB model and reconsider the table naming as it is not recommended to write full decimal table name. Are you sure you need table instead of rows ? Why don't you link two tables or convert to a better string format

Comment: well, the data I have from user, It generates new IDs every day and 800+ entries each day ,  So after a year or 3 years if someone wants to search today's certain entry , Wouldn't it be  slow procedure.

Comment: PLus Really thnaks for reply that Fast , I never expected this much Fast replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table name cannot start with a numeric unless forced.

You can force by enclosing the table name in `[table_name]`, `'table_name'`, `"table_name"` or `table_name` .

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [MikeT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48805660/7294647), you also have a typo in your code:

> "id integer primany"

`primany` should be `primary`

Comment: Yup , that including Xd, Thanks allot for helping , i never expected that much instant replies.